# Hibernate transient fields

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Consider the following scenario where a JPA entity `EntityA` has a transient field consisting of a list of `EntityB` entities, where a `ManyToOne` mapping exists between `EntityB` and `EntityA`:

```
@Entity
class EntityA {
    @Id
    Long ID;

    @Transient
    List<EntityB> entityBList;
}

@Entity
class EntityB {
    @Id
    Long ID;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_a_id")
    private EntityA entityA;
}
```

Suppose we load an `EntityA` and the corresponding list of entities `EntityB` from the DB (managed entities) and we set the list to `EntityA`'s transient field, `entityBList`.

I intend to use the transient field merely as a transfer object. Then I intend to perform write operations with the parent entity (EntityA). Given that the list of entities B is loaded into the persistent context (they become managed), I suppose after saving and flushing the parent entity, EntityA, in case any of the entities B gets "dirty" and despite them being assigned to a transient field, there will be consequences in the DB, right? What are other unintended repercussions of using this "hack"? What could go wrong?